# Is there a difference between new foo() and just foo()?

Tags: javascript, new-operator

In Javascript, is there any difference between calling `new foo()` and simply `foo()`?

In other languages, the new keyword is required, but in Javascript, since Objects are created via functions as constructors, the `new` keyword should be neither necessary nor beneficial in any way.

For instance:

```
function foo(){ 
    return { a:2, b:3, hello: 'world' }
}
```

If I call `new foo()`, it returns the same result as `foo()`.

I know the newest ECMAscript spec has classes which would maybe need the new keyword, but I really only care about function object constructors.

Comment: The 'new' operator is key to implement prototypal inheritance. A good explanation of this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript Best.

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448890/trying-to-understand-the-new-keyword?rq=1

Comment: If the function returns an object, then there is no difference between `new func()` and `func()`. I recommend to read the MDN documentation about `new`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript?rq=1

Comment: It's actually not a duplicate of that question. This question is about `foo()` and `new foo()`, the other is about `function() {}` and `new function() {}` which is the same as `foo` and `new foo`.

Comment: I looked for that question, I swear I tried.

Comment: *"I know the newest ECMAscript spec has classes which would maybe need the new keyword"* That really is just syntactic sugar for constructor functions. The way how JS works internally doesn't change, it's still a prototype based language.

Comment: @FelixKling is right, this isn't a duplicate of the currently linked question. It is a duplicate of this one though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript

Comment: @lukkea I wouldn't call this a duplicate of that at all. This question is much more specific. The answer to this question might be in one of the answers to that question, but the questions are very different.